# 配列の欠落したデータを補完したい

Tags: ruby

こんにちは。

Ruby のプログラムで、日付と数値が入った配列のうち欠落した要素に対して補完をしたいと思っております。
開始・終了日が決まっていますので、その間のデータがなければ配列に値を挿入、その後ソートして出力しております。
目的は下記のプログラムで実現できているのですが、 Ruby っぽさがないと思っております。 Ruby っぽさを求めるならこうだ！というのがあればよろしくお願いします。

```
require "date"

arr = [
         ["2015-03-01", 200],
         ["2015-03-02", 200],
         ["2015-03-04", 200],
         ["2015-03-05", 200],
         ["2015-03-06", 200],
       ]

begin_date = "2015-03-01"
end_date = "2015-03-07"

(Date.parse(begin_date)..Date.parse(end_date)).each do |date|

    unless arr.find{|a| a.first == date.to_s} then
        arr << [date.to_s, nil]
    end
end

puts arr.sort_by{|a| a.first}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubyらしいかは分かりませんが、ちょっとだけ書き換えてみました。多分こっちの方が速いと思うのですが。

```
require "date"

arr = [
        ["2015-03-01", 200],
        ["2015-03-02", 200],
        ["2015-03-04", 200],
        ["2015-03-05", 200],
        ["2015-03-06", 200],
      ]

begin_date = "2015-03-01"
end_date = "2015-03-07"
h = arr.to_h

(Date.parse(begin_date)..Date.parse(end_date)).each do |date|
  h[date.to_s] = nil unless h[date.to_s]
end

puts h.sort
```

Answer (score 2):

面白そうなので参戦（？）します。

日付をキーにするHashを作り、最初から最後までループさせながらvalueを集めていくロジックにしました。  
キーがなければnilが返ります。

あと、以下のような点を変更しています。

- メインロジックのメソッド化
- 変数等のリネーム
- DRYにできるところは極力DRYに
- テストの追加

参考にしてみてください。

```
require 'date'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestComplementBlank < Minitest::Test
  def complement_blank(data_array, date_from, date_to)
    data_table = data_array.to_h
    from_to = [date_from, date_to].map { |s| Date.parse(s) }
    Range.new(*from_to).map(&:to_s).map { |date| [date, data_table[date]] }
  end

  def test_complement_blank
    date_from = '2015-03-01'
    date_to = '2015-03-07'
    data_array = [
        ['2015-03-01', 200],
        ['2015-03-02', 200],
        ['2015-03-04', 200],
        ['2015-03-05', 200],
        ['2015-03-06', 200]
    ]
    expected = [
        ['2015-03-01', 200],
        ['2015-03-02', 200],
        ['2015-03-03', nil],
        ['2015-03-04', 200],
        ['2015-03-05', 200],
        ['2015-03-06', 200],
        ['2015-03-07', nil]
    ]
    assert_equal expected, complement_blank(data_array, date_from, date_to)
  end
end
```

#### 追記

sanadanさんの回答は面白いですね。
Hash#sortがそんなふうに使えるとは知りませんでした。

sanadanさんの回答をベースにするとこんな書き方もでます。

```
def complement_blank(data_array, date_from, date_to)
  from_to = [date_from, date_to].map { |s| Date.parse(s) }
  Range.new(*from_to)
    .each_with_object(data_array.to_h) { |date, h| h[date.to_s] ||= nil }
    .sort
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby っぽさが出てるかどうか分かりませんが。
日付だけの配列を作って、配列の差を取ることで足りない配列要素の元を作ってみました。
各日に1要素だけ、最終的に日付順ソートする、という前提であればこのようなものでも OK でしょう。

```
require "date"

arr = [
  ["2015-03-01", 200],
  ["2015-03-02", 200],
  ["2015-03-04", 200],
  ["2015-03-05", 200],
  ["2015-03-06", 200],
]

begin_date = "2015-03-01"
end_date = "2015-03-07"

date_arr = arr.map(&:first) # 日付分だけの配列を作る
cont_date_arr = [*Date.parse(begin_date)..Date.parse(end_date)].map(&:to_s) # 日付分だけの連続した配列
miss_arr = cont_date_arr - date_arr # arrに無かった日付の配列
arr.concat(miss_arr.map{ |d| [d, nil] }).sort_by!(&:first)
puts arr
```

`puts` だと `nil` が見えないのが気になりますが…。

Comment: 各日に１要素とはどういうことでしょうか配列arrの200のことでしょうか？

Comment: arr = [["2015-03-01", 200], ["2015-03-01", 200], ..]のように、同じ"2015-03-01"に関連した複数の要素が存在している場合には、配列の差を取ったやりかたはNGですので、その意味で記載しました。ややこしい記載をして申し訳ないです。

Comment: 納得です。日付に関しては重複しません。実はRailsのコードでユニーク制約をつけているので大丈夫なんです。

Answer (score 1):

```
require "date"

arr = [
     ["2015-03-01", 200],
     ["2015-03-02", 200],
     ["2015-03-04", 200],
     ["2015-03-05", 200],
     ["2015-03-06", 200],
   ]

begin_date = "2015-03-01"
end_date = "2015-03-07"

hash = {}
arr_hash = Hash[*arr.flatten]
(Date.parse(begin_date)..Date.parse(end_date)).each do |date|
  hash[date.to_s] = arr_hash[date.to_s]
end
p hash.to_a
```

実行例：

```
$ ruby arr.rb
[["2015-03-01", 200], ["2015-03-02", 200], ["2015-03-03", nil], ["2015-03-04", 200], ["2015-03-05", 200], ["2015-03-06", 200], ["2015-03-07", nil]]
```